# Is this expression correct?: "It would not be true if we said..."

Tags: grammar

Here is the whole sentence:
It would not be true if we said there are no concerns about carrying out the performance.

Does it make sense in English or are there more natural ways to phrase this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's grammatical and idiomatic - although it would also be correct if you said **....there were no concerns....** following the past tense verb **said**.

Comment: I would have more issues with "carrying out the performance" though I will note that the sentence is being elliptical.  (Sometime you need to be.)

Comment: @RonaldSole Thank you for your comment! If we still may have concerns in the near future, should I say "It would not be true if we say there are no concerns about carrying out the performance."?

Comment: @Mary Thank you for pointing out! What should I say instead of "carrying out"? I want to imply there are some concerns for the whole process of the performance (including preparation period, not just the day of the performance) so "presenting the performance" would not be appropriate...

Comment: I would say, "carrying out the tasks for the performance" in that case.